# Stretch div inside a parent div with display: table-cell

Tags: css

I have a div inside a parent div. The parent div has display set to table-cell and does not have a fixed size.

I need the child div to stretch throughout the parent div, but I need the parent div to retain its size and not stretch itself.

This is my code (with inline CSS for simplicity):

```
<div style="display:table;">
  <div style="display:table-cell;"></div>
  <div style="display:table-cell; width: 600px;">Content</div>
  <div id="parent" style="display:table-cell;">
    <div id="child"></div> <!-- I need to stretch this across the entire parent -->
  </div>
</div>
```

This is basically what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

In other words: three divs in a line, the middle having a fixed size, the other ones stretching to the ends of the browser window. I need to be able to add content to the right div *while* making sure the right div doesn't resize as I add content into it.

Comment: Is it possible to show us a picture of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I could not understand sorry, any image what you want achieve ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}
.child {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.child.fixed {
  flex: 0 0 600px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child fixed"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Or if you must use CSS Tables - [**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jqevmW)

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
.child {
  display: table-cell;
  background: lightgrey;
}
.child.fixed {
  width: 600px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child fixed"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is it. I will use the second option since flex is not very well supported by IEs yet (http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="browser-window">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.browser-window {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  display: table;
}
.left, .middle, .right {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
}
.middle {
  width: 60px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6gzegpzx/

Comment: @Ondrej does this answer not fix your issue?

Comment: Sadly it doesn't, since when I do this, the child div stretches across the parent and the parent also stretches as much as it can, so, the image in above your answer would appear without the div on the left (its size would be 0), while the middle and right divs would stretch throughout the browser window.